# Generating multiple network graphs with attributes from csv with ggraph, tidygraph in R

Tags: r, networking, graph, ggraph, tidygraph

I have three csv files which looks like this:

```
node <- data.frame(
object = c("2-1887", "2-1887", "2-1887", "2-1887", "2-1887", "2-1887", "2-1887", "4-1889", "4-1889", "4-1889", "4-1889", "4-1889", "4-1889", "4-1889"),
id = c(1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7),
function = c("f", "r", "r", "c", "s", "r", "k", "f", "r", "s", "r", "r", "r", "t"))

edge <- data.frame(
object = c("2-1887", "2-1887", "2-1887", "2-1887", "2-1887", "2-1887", "2-1887", "4-1889", "4-1889", "4-1889", "4-1889", "4-1889", "4-1889", "4-1889"),
from = c(1, 2, 3, 3, 4, 5, 6, 1, 2, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6),
to = c(2, 3, 4, 6, 6, 6, 7, 2, 3, 4, 4, 5, 6, 7))

meta <- data.frame(
object = c("2-1887", "4-1889"),
year = c(2000, 2022))
```

Actually this data set contains two different graphs grouped by `object`.

Is anyone who can advice how to generate two graphs grouped by `object` ("2-1887" and "4-1889") using `tbl_graph` in `ggraph/tidygraph`? It is nice if I can keep these object names in graph attributes.
I suppose I can do it with `purrr` or `apply` (any methods are welcomed) but I do not know appropriate data structure (list?) for further graph analyses.

I also need to add meta information (graph attributes) to each graph from an object `meta`. Currently I can add graph attributes manually using such as `graph$year <- 2000` but I need to automate it.

Thank you in advance for your kind support.

Comment: can you make it reproducible? What is function? should those be strings?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
edge %>%
  group_by(object) %>%
  summarise(graph = list(igraph::graph_from_data_frame(cur_data()))) %>%
  left_join(meta)

# A tibble: 2 x 3
  object graph     year
  <chr>  <list>   <dbl>
1 2-1887 <igraph>  2000
2 4-1889 <igraph>  2022
```

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion. I realized that an attribute `function` was disappeared after the manipulation.  Any ways to keep it?